# How to retrieve data from fire base real-time data which has 2 child layer to listView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Example of data in real time databse]

How can retrieve the data in  Event folder which has two child?
I'm new to android studio...

Sample code as below:

```
database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    ref = database.getReference("Event");
    list = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.event_info,R.id.eventTitle,list);
    ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren())
            {
                eventInfo = ds.getValue(EventInfo.class);
                list.add(eventInfo.getTitle() + " \n " + eventInfo.getAddress() +
                        " \n " + eventInfo.getDescription() + " \n " + eventInfo.getImgURL() +
                        " \n " + eventInfo.getLatitude() + " \n " + eventInfo.getLongitude());
            }

            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you loop over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`, each child is itself a `DataSnapshot` again. So you can loop over the children of that one too. Since you have two dynamic levels in your JSON, you need two nested loops in your code:

```
ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Event");
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot userSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            for(DataSnapshot eventSnapshot: userSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                eventInfo = eventSnapshot.getValue(EventInfo.class);
                Log.d("Event", eventSnapshot.getKey());
                Log.d("Event", eventSnapshot.child("title").getValue(String.class));
            }
        }
    }
    ...
```